# Compare predictions of 10 models

Tags: statistical-significance, predictive-models, loss-functions, model-comparison

I am aiming to compare predictions made using 10 different models with no reference to the observed value. The objective is two folds : i- check if the difference between the models predictions are significative ii- and which are the models that are similar to each other in terms of predictions.

For that purpose, I thought about adopting a matrix (10*10) where each Column/Line intersection will refer to the distance between the predictions (First decision to make, which distance method to choose). The second decision concerns the test to adopt to check whether the difference between the predictions is significant or not.

Any orientations regarding the distance method & the test to choose for the purpose of this study ?

Regards

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are the predictions based on 1-parameter only? What is the range of admissible values for the variable they want to predict?

Comment: Caro Federico. Indeed the predictions are based on 1 parameter, and the output variable is continuous ranging from 0 to 2500.